# Por que o decorator do método é executado antes da classe ser instanciada?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Eu estava a investigar sobre uso de decorators em routers do express do nodejs, e encontrei o seguinte turorial [How to make REST API’s using Node.js, Express.js & Typescript Decorators](https://medium.com/@rsharma0011/how-to-make-rest-apis-using-node-js-express-js-typescript-decorators-5fd468e0f3c9)

Analisando o código, percebi que a classe da controller Users (`Users.controller.ts`) recebe o decorator `@routesDecorator` em um de seu método e a mesma é importada para o `server.ts` porém **não é instanciada**. Executando o projeto por completo é funcional, mas não entendo o porque.

**Users.controller.ts**

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import routesDecorator from '../decorators/routes.decorator';

export class Users {
    @routesDecorator({
        path: '/users',
        method: 'get'
    })
    getUsers(req: Request, res: Response) {
        res.send('Typescript Decorators are awesome !!!');
    }
}
```

**routes.decorator.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
export const appRouter = Router();

interface IOptions {
    path: string;
    method: 'get'| 'post'| 'put' | 'delete' ;
    middlewares?: any[],
}

function routesDecorator(options: IOptions) {
    return (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) => {
       (appRouter as any)[options.method](options.path, target[propertyKey]);
    };
}

export default routesDecorator;
```

**server.ts**

```
import * as express from 'express';
const app = express();
import './controllers';
import { appRouter } from './decorators/routes.decorator';

app.use(appRouter);app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

Seria algum go horse que foi aproveitado pós transpilação do typescript, ou é um comportamento padrão?